# How to get text from checked boxes using bs4?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

im trying to get all the labels (text) from the boxes that are checked off (or questions answered) on the following site.

however i seem to not get any text out instead.

Further more the way i thought of doing the scraping, was to collect all the links first - in the right side you can switch between the pages. It also seems like this list have all links times 2...

Here is my current code (see link in there as well called `main_url`)

```
import bs4 as bs
from splinter import Browser
import time



executable_path = {'executable_path' :'C:/users/chromedriver.exe'}
browser = Browser('chrome', **executable_path)

main_url = 'https://reporting.unpri.org/surveys/PRI-Reporting-Framework-
2016/0ad07cdc-cfbc-4c5b-a79f-
2b07e93d8521/79894dbc337a40828d895f9402aa63de/html/2/?lang=&a=1'
browser.visit(main_url)
source = browser.html
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
base_url = main_url[:-51]
urls = []
print(base_url)

for i in soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'accordion-inner n-accordion-link'):
    for j in soup.find_all('a', class_ = 'tooltiper'):
        urls.append(j['href'])

print(urls)

result = []
for k in urls:
    ext = k[8:]
    browser.visit(base_url + ext)
    source1 = browser.html
    soup1 = bs.BeautifulSoup(source1, 'lxml')
    temp_list = []
    print(browser.url)
    for img in soup1.find_all('img', class_ = 'readradio'):
        for t in img['src']:
            if t == '/Style/img/checkedradio.png':
                for x in soup1.find_all('span', class_ = 'title'):
                    txt = str(x.string)
                    temp_list.append(txt)

result.append(temp_list)
print(result)
```

I get the following output for the results list, which is supposed to contain the text:

```
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

---

Updated code with suggestion:

```
import bs4 as bs
from splinter import Browser
import time



executable_path = {'executable_path' 
:'/users/nichlasrasmussen/documents/webdrivers/phantomjs'}
browser = Browser('phantomjs', **executable_path)

main_url = 'https://reporting.unpri.org/surveys/PRI-Reporting-Framework-
2016/0ad07cdc-cfbc-4c5b-a79f-
2b07e93d8521/79894dbc337a40828d895f9402aa63de/html/2/?lang=&a=1'
browser.visit(main_url)
source = browser.html
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
base_url = main_url[:-51]
urls = []
print(base_url)

for i in soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'accordion-inner n-accordion-link'):
    for j in soup.find_all('a', class_ = 'tooltiper'):
        urls.append(j['href'])

    print(urls)

result = []
for k in urls:
    ext = k[8:]
    browser.visit(base_url + ext)
    source1 = browser.html
    soup1 = bs.BeautifulSoup(source1, 'lxml')
    temp_list = []
    print(browser.url)
    for label in soup1.find_all('label', class_='radio'):
    t = label.find('img', class_='readradio')
    if 'checkedradio' in t['src']:
        content = soup1.find('span', class_='title')
        temp_list.append(content.text)

result.append(temp_list)
print(result)
```

Comment: what's the output?

Comment: Sorry, i update the question now.

Comment: what happens when you set your parser to `html` instead of `lxml`?

Comment: Same exact ouput.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can basically just refer to the parent of both the `img` and `span.title` elements which is the `label.radio`.

No need to do a tremendous loop starting from root (`soup1`)

Try this:

```
for label in soup1.find_all('label', class_='radio'):
    t = label.find('img', class_='readradio')
    if t and '/Style/img/checkedradio.png' in t.get('src'):
        content = label.find('span', class_='title')
        temp_list.append(content.text)
```

Comment: i get the following error:

"ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?...... for the last line

Comment: I also get:

if 'checkedradio' in t['src']:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: This should replace all your loops starting from `for img in soup1.find_all('img', class_ = 'readradio'):`

Comment: Yes, that is what i tried as well. I will update question, with a section of the code including your loop.

Comment: I still get the following error, with the updated code: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Documents/sd.py", line 34, in <module>
    if 'checkedradio' in t['src']:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable